# I mistakenly used Ethereum Network for my Arbitrium Address & I am unable to access the funds on it

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I accidentally selected network as arbitrium but the transactions are done on the Ethereum network for the same address displayed as Ethereum on my gnosis safe wallet. The transactions are visible on etherscan and I can see the Eth along with the logs on it. Is there any way to recover the funds or update the Safe Dashboard?

Comment: You try looking at this https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover